# Why do I keep getting the error "AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'writerows" when using csv module?

Tags: python, csv

I am imported CSV and the way the documents told me to do it resulted in failures.

Here is the code that is having the problems.

```
outfile = open("D:/stock_information/processed data/standard_deviant.csv", "w")
write_outfile = csv.writer(outfile)

for i in range(len(all_standard_deviant_info)):
    outfile.writerows(all_standard_deviant_info[i][0])
    outfile.writerows(all_standard_deviant_info[i][1])
```

Does anyone know why it's saying .writerows doesn't exist?

Comment: Use `write_outfile` instead of `outfile`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use,

```
write_outfile.writerows(all_standard_deviant_info[i][0])
```

Because `outfile` is just a file object not a `csv.writer`'s object.

Comment: Thank you that did exactly what I was looking for. Sorry about asking such a simple question.